# If "v" is a linear combination of "u" and "w" in $\mathbb{R}^4$, show that {T (u), T (v), T (w)} is a linearly dependent set.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm not sure where to start.

$\rightarrow$ T is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^4$→ $\mathbb{R}^4$.

$\rightarrow$ $\overrightarrow{v}$ is a linear combination of $\overrightarrow{u}$ and $\overrightarrow{w}$.

$\rightarrow$ Proving  {T (u), T (v), T (w)} are linearly dependent.

Comment: They satisfy the same linear equation.

Comment: If $v = \alpha u + \beta w$, then $Tv = \alpha Tu + \beta Tw$.